# Passing List of Objects (referenced) to BaseAdapter extended Class and call notifyDataSetChanged() not Working after changing reference

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I am doing this for the understanding. In my case I have a class extended by `BaseAdapter`. in the new class I am passing the list of objects I want to bind to the `ListView` in android and I keep a reference to that passing list of objects.

```
ListView list2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.attachmentList);
    list2.setAdapter(new LazyAdapter(BaseAdapterExtention.this,getApplication().getInteraction().getList() ));
```

Like above I keep the data that I am passing as a singleton `getApplication().getInteraction().getList()` which I call this to get the data.

Each list item has a button, and each list item button has a click listener, when a button is clicked, I am deleting that item and repopulate the data set in the singleton object as below

`getApplication().getInteraction().setList(listofObjects)`.

to do that I am calling an async task and I am passing this adapter

```
new ListAsync(activity,BaseAdapterExtention.this).execute();
```

and in `onPostExecute()` I call the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. but the adapter object list is the same, the deletion is not reflected in that list and so, the `list view` is the same.

What's wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a public method in the Activity that has the ListView and there,

```
public void notifyDataChangeInAdapter(){
        list2.setAdapter(new BaseAdapterExtention(ExampleActivity.this, getApplication().getInteraction().getList() ));
}
```

I am calling this method in onPostExecute() method by using the activity reference that I passed to that asynctask constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `adapter.clear()` before calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

By doing `adapter.clear()` it removes all elements from the adapter and then by using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` it notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set will update now without any problem.

**Edit**

As you are extending `BaseAdapter`, `.clear()` won't work.Hence you could call `list2.setAdapter()` again and pass null like this:

```
list2.setAdapter(null);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks, I have checked the this,there is no method definition called 'clear()'for the BaseAdapter extended class

Comment: Okay you're right.`when a button is clicked, I am deleting that item` How are you deleting actually?By calling `.remove()` on your List(items)?

Comment: get hold of the bound object info (id) and delete that in the database, and re aquire the data from the db and then set them in the singleton refernece

Comment: Ok, if I am using this, I will have to pass a reference of list2 to the async task, I will mark this as a correct answer, if that is working like this. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes you will need to do that.I think setting the data behind `list2` to `null` will do the trick.Give it a try.